Transiting to Canada through Barcelona and Athens airport
I'm an Indian, holding both American and Canadian visit visas. Do I still need to have a transit visa at Barcelona and Athens airports?

If you are not leaving the international area you might not need any transit visa but it’s unfortunate affair to be honest requiring all these visas

@SaranshSharma it is not possible to fly between Athens and Barcelona without leaving the international area of the airport because both Greece and Spain are in the Schengen area.

Indian citizens need a visa to enter Schengen area, so you'll need a visa if you're going through immigration in either of this airports (for example, if your connections include a flight between Barcelona and Athens).
In Spain (Barcelona), Indian citizens need a transit visa even in the international area of the airport, but if you have a US or Canadian visa you're exempt from that requirement.

Let's make it clear that in the first case, it's a full Schengen visa which is required (type C), not an airport transit visa (ATV). This applies both if there is an internal Schengen flight such as BCN-ATH and in the case of a self-transfer. Also for BCN, while the page linked does not state so, I believe the rule is that US and Canada visas are a valid exemption for an ATV only if one is travelling to or from the relevant country (contrary to residence permits which do not have this requirement).

@jcaron the Spanish consulate doesn't state that condition, so I don't know what you're basing it on. Regardless, the OP stated they're in fact traveling to the relevant country.

@jcaron the conditions of the exemption are specified by the Schengen Visa Code and should be the same everywhere even if the list of nationalities requiring the airport transit visa is variable.

@phoog And the Schengen Visa Code says that visas are valid only for travel to/from the relevant country. It's not completely impossible that Spain added more exemptions, but that would be surprising.

@jcaron the condition is "when travelling to the issuing country or to any other third country, or when, having used the visa, returning from the issuing country." (Emphasis added)
